# How to use items in a list as arguments to a function in LISP?

Tags: list, function, arguments, lisp, common-lisp

This is for a school assignment.

I wrote multiple functions, each with a different amount of arguments. I am required to create a REPL function that works with all of the functions in my project.

For every function:

- Prompt user for a **list** of arguments.

  - If the user enters nil, stop, move to the next function
  - If the user enters valid input (a list of arguments), call the function using the items of that list.
  - **Assume no invalid input is ever entered.**

Here is what I have so far as my REPL function:

```
(setq funcList '(append. reverse map fold member insert intersection
                 union abs factorial right-tri gcd perfectp abundantp
                 deficientp))

(defun repl ()
  (loop for f in funcList do
    (loop
      (format t "Enter a list of arguments for ~s (NIL to stop): " f)
      (setq argsList (read))
      (when (eq argsList nil) return nil)
      (format t "(~s arguments-here) => output-of-function-here" f)
    )
  )
)
```

I am a total beginner when it comes to lisp, so please feel free to criticize my code.

In any case, what I want to do is use the items in the list that I prompt the user to input as the different arguments required by the current function the user is testing. I would then call the function using something along the lines of:

`(funcall f arg1 arg2...argk)`

I do not know in what way I can separate the items in the list into separate arguments.

Is there any way to do that? I am not required to do it with a list, so examples of different ways are more than welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have a list of arguments that are used simultaneously with the function. For example, if the function is + and you have the list argsList '(1 2 3), you just need to do (apply func argsList) => 6

Comment: @Leo Are there other ways of doing it? I'm just curious.

Comment: You could do (eval (cons '+ args)). If the arguments are not grouped into a list, you can also use (funcall #'+ 1 2 3). Also, in the particular case of +, which takes any number of arguments, you could use (reduce '+ args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that applies functions to a list of arguments is called [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm) in Lisp.  Different Lisps have had slightly different conventions for `apply`, but all Lisp-family languages that I know of have some variant.  It's an essential part of writing something like an evaluator for Lisp.